# JAVA: different results when applying iteration for a single program

Tags: java, eclipse

Recently, I wrote a program that works fine. And I want multiple results by applying different random seeds for the program which includes a random method. I did it in two ways, one is to change the random seed manually for 30times, by running it for each seed we can obtain one result; the other way is to add a "for" loop to generate the same random seeds as those used in the first method, finally by running it, I got multiple (30) results. The problem is that when I compare the results one by one with the results of first method, some of them are different. I feel confused, please help me on this.

I may describe it as follows to make you more clear.

Assume my single program to be "void sp(int i)", where "i" is the interface for the seed.

(1) The first method is to change the "i" of the single program manually, and run it one by one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int sample = 0; //sample is the random seed: 0, 1, 2, ..., 29
            sp(sample);

     }
```

(2) The second method is to add a "for" loop to generate the random seeds.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for(int sample = 0; sample < 30; sample ++){ //sample is the random seed

                sp(sample);

            }
     }
```

The 10th, 16th, and 28th results are different. Why could it happen, and how to deal with it.

My platform is DELL OPTIPLEX 960, OS is Windows 7 (64-bit) and the software is

Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600.

Thanks in advance.

Along

Comment: there is not enough code/context to make an analysis.

Comment: The code you should provide must allow to reproduce the problem. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The method "void sp(int i)" is not just one method, it contains a lot more without comments and is annoying to anyone else I think.

Comment: I found the problem comes from the HashMap I used. Comparing the first (manual) and second (iterative) method, after using the HashMap.put(), output sequences are different when using HashMap.keySet(). But I do not know why this could happen? @AbbéRésina

Comment: Sorry, but you ask questions without providing the code that could help people understand your problem.